# apache and httpd running but I can't see my website

Tags: apache, centos

I have installed apache on my server however I can not browse my website through my server's IP. the setup of the apache is a single account server under /var/www/htdocs/.

Is there anything else I need to do to be able to see the account via my server's IP?

Comment: closed as of topic? shouldn't this question just be moved to another stack exchange site like serverfault?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

There are several possibilities.

- firewall, iptables configuration
- apache listen address / port

More information is needed about your configuration.  What distro are you using?  Can you connect via 127.0.0.1?

If the issue is with the firewall/iptables, you can add the following lines to /etc/sysconfig/iptables:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

(Second line is only needed for https)

Make sure this is above any lines that would globally restrict access, like the following:

```
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

Tested on CentOS 6.3

And finally

```
service iptables restart
```

Comment: I am using centos, and by default usually when I get a server, apache is installed on it, or if its not when I install apache I can see the htdocs folder via the IP adress... however right now thats not happening!! the config is the default config of centos and I have only changed the html folder to htdocs in the httpd config file.

Comment: Are you sure apache is running?  CentOS does not start it by default. sudo /etc/init.d/httpd start

Also check /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf, uncomment the ServerName directive and give it a host name.

Comment: you were right, it was the firewall config!! blocking all the IPs!!!

Comment: Don't forget `service iptables restart`

Comment: To check if it's a firewall problem, just do `service iptables stop` and if it works, then you know the problem is within iptables.

Comment: Centos7 enables `firewalld` by default.  In my case this is what was causing the described symptoms.  Since I do not need firewalld, I ran the commands `sudo systemctl disable firewalld` and `sudo systemctl stop firewalld` to access my web server remotely.

Answer (score 1):

Did you restart the server after you changed the config file?

Can you telnet to the server from a different machine?

Can you telnet to the server from the server itself?

telnet <ip address> 80

telnet localhost 80