# Unable to serve https with apache/centos

Tags: apache, ssl, https, centos, httpd.conf

I have an apache server set up on CentOS. I am trying to add SSL. I was able to create the certificate and keys and then updated `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf` to have the following configurations:

**/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf**

```
#Where I put my cert
SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca.crt

#where I put my key
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/ca.key
```

Then I updated `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`:

**/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf**

```
Listen 443
NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/ca.key
</VirtualHost>
```

Then I ran `service httpd restart` and everything is ok

```
Stopping httpd:          [OK]
Starting httpd:          [OK]
```

But when I go to my site with https, it says "This webpage is not available". What do i need to do to enable https?

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to open the 443 port in iptables: [apache and httpd running but I cant see my website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936606/apache-and-httpd-running-but-i-cant-see-my-website)

To alter this (on Centos 6), add the below line to the file `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

You need to make sure this is **above** any of the lines that are restricting access globally.